# EOF Exception : Input contained no data in cmd

Tags: maven, exception, cmd, eof

When trying to invoke mvn --encrypt-password password in cmd, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
[ERROR] Caused by: input contained no data
```

When I invoke mvn --encrypt-master-password somepass, it executes normally. Can someone help me with the solution or how can I print the whole stacktrace to find the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to type your password and can't give it via parameter based on security...(never put a password into a cmd file)

Comment: so how should I do it?

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a master password first.  If you were following the tutorial [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html) you cannot skip the step of creating the master password (like I did) or you will get the error above.

Run the command:

```
mvn --encrypt-master-password
```

Enter your master password at the prompt.  Enter the output of that command into your `${user.home}/.m2/settings-security.xml` file as follows

```
<settingsSecurity>
    <master>{jSMOWnoPFgsHVpMvz5VrIt5kRbzGpI8u+9EF1iFQyJQ=}</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

Now, your `mvn --encrypt-password <yourPassword>` command should work.

Comment: @green did that fix your issues?

Answer (score 0):

```
org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcherException: java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
at org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecUtil.read (SecUtil.java:66)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.encryption (MavenCli.java:924)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:291)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

settings-security.xml is not parsing in mxparser, add xml header in settings-security.xml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, it will resolve the issue.